# Summation of polygon along a line

Tags: qgis, shapefile, area

I have a large polygon shapefile with individual features with multiple lines intersecting these (see photo).

I am trying to find the point along the line where the summation of the polygons connected by the line upstream is equal or greater than a certain value.

Polygons were created from another programme and they are not in any kind of order, there is 200+ so would be time consuming to give each a logical ID. I've created an ID column to show which line they are connected too.

[image: Catchment and Streamline Screenshot]

Comment: I found a way to do this through the Statistics Panel and gradually highlighting each catchment typing the forumla $Area and making notes.  It wasn't too time consuming but it would do okay. 
Just curious if anyone knows a more automated way?